# Reversing UITableView scrolling behaviour

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse the scrolling behaviour of UITableView, like when the default swipe up guesture is detected it would scroll down (instead of scrolling up , which is the default behaviour) and vice versa.
This probably requires hacking the UIScrollView behind the UITableView , but i can't figure out a way to implement that...
Please notice this isn't destinated for AppStore approval , so I don't mind using undocumented methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Apple will ever approve an app with such inverted gesture. Anyway if you want to experiment, you must subclass UITableView and detect touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly state that you're not looking for app store approval, check out Matt Gallagher's post on [Synthesizing a touch event on the iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html), but heed his warning:

> The content of this post is for
>   debugging and testing only. Do not
>   submit this code in an application to
>   the App Store. Doing so will likely
>   result in:
>
> - A bad UI experience for your users.
> - An
>     app that breaks on every OS update.
> - Rejection of your application.
>
> Synthesized touches are never the
>   right way to trigger actions in a real
>   application. The only useful use for
>   this post is in automated user testing

Comment: The example in this post isn't functional as of iOS 4.2 .... any other suggestions ?